# Updating discourse

Tags: terminal, tar, discourse

Anyone know why this line in these updating instructions don't work.

https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-ubuntu.md#updating-discourse

DATESTAMP=$(TZ=UTC date +%F-%T)
pg_dump --no-owner --clean discourse_prod | gzip -c > ~/discourse-db-$DATESTAMP.sql.gz
tar cfz ~/discourse-dir-$DATESTAMP.tar.gz -C /var/www discourse

The first 2 lines work and I can see the .gz file being created in my home directory. 
But when I run the third line `tar cfz ~/discourse-dir-$DATESTAMP.tar.gz -C /mydiscourse directory` it fails and give me an error:

> tar: no files or directories specified

I even changed it to

```
tar cfz ~/discourse-db-$DATESTAMP.tar.gz -C /mydiscourse directory
```

because db is the name of the file. not dir but this still is giving me an error. Does anyone know what this could be?

Comment: Anyone know why this might be happening ?

Comment: try our docker install